# How to Convert from fixeddocument to xls

Tags: wpf, xls, fixeddocument

How do I Convert from fixeddocument to xls?

Is there is a way to convert from a fixeddocument to xls? I am using a fixeddocument to print xps but now I need the "save as xls" option.

Do I have to loop through all the controls in the fixeddocument in order to convert it into xls one row at a time? Or is there a better way? I need to keep the formatting and layout as is.

I am not looking for a third party control.